# Grails GORM. Adding mappings to existing hibernate mappings

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I use grails with a legacy database, all hibernate classes and their mappings are packaged in a jar file and reside in the grails lib folder. Querying/updating/inserting with GORM works ok.
Now I would like to add some mappings, let's say I want to add the mapping:

```
id column:'person_id'
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't an easy way to do this. You can *either* map a class using Hibernate mapping classes *or* use the custom mapping DSL. But you can't use both on a single class.

In fact, to use the mapping DSL you have to create a standard GORM domain class under `grails-app/domain`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this if you hook into the grails compilation early on, but really complicated.

See:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Add-a-dynamic-property-to-a-domain-class-td1392630.html

According to: 
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5449

this can possibly be done using AST transformations.

Let me know if you ever solve this.